# How can I extend jQuery's $.ajax to support new content types?

Tags: jquery, msgpack

I would like to be able to send and receive [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)-formatted data with jQuery's `$.ajax()`. How does one extend `$.ajax()` to support new `Content-Type` formats?

Comment: A string is a string, jQuery datatypes only help you by converting the string to object, html, xml etc. So just send the string, and do your own parsing.

Comment: Sure, but it's nice the way jQuery automatically parses `json` responses for me. If I can extend jQuery's content-type recognition, then I could potentially switch a project from `application/json` to `application/msgpack` without peppering the codebase with calls to the parser.

Comment: You can just write your own reusable function to do that, without extending $.ajax, but you could of course extend the $.ajax function if that's what you want, but it will be more complicated than writing a new ajax function that uses $.ajax internally, and parses and returns the results for you.

Comment: There's a method `$.ajaxPrefilter()` that looks like it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.ajaxPrefilter()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/), which allows you to define custom processing before the AJAX request is sent.

To process custom types of returned data, use the `converters` option to `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()`.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious from the docs how to use these. `$.ajaxPrefilter()` handles request processing, while `converters` handles response processing?

Comment: Yeah, the documentation isn't very good on this. Your best bet is to read the jQuery source code to see how it's used internally for the predefined types.